# html5 collisioin detection and creating multiple enemies

Tags: javascript, html, collision-detection

Welcome. I want to create function that will check if objects collides. I want to use 2d box collision but I have no idea how to get X position from enemy that is created in other .js file. The variable of position X is changed in function AnimacjeOb. Here is jsFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/q4wyz7na/.

The collision detecting code that I'm trying to create looks like this :

```
mobki = start.mobki,

function kol (x ,y, xp, yp, x2, y2, x2p, y2p){
    return !(xp <= x2 || x > x2p || yp <= y2 || y > y2p);
}

function koli (poz, size){
    return kol (poz[0], poz[1],
                poz [0] + size[0], poz[1]+ size[1]);

}

function sprKolizje(){
    for (var i = 0; i < mobki.tworz.tabPot.length; i++){ 
        var poz = mobki.animacja.pozX;   //this is where error pop out
        var size = 60;

        if (koli(poz, size)){
            mobki.tworz.splice (i, 1);
            i--;    
        }
    }
}
```

But executing this program will return error "Cannot read property 'tworz' of undefined". How can i get variable that store and update position X from other .js file?

Comment: Your fiddle fails in the first line, and I don't speak Polish, so I suggest you debug it enough to reach your actual error.

Comment: To make code in this fiddle works i need to upload all my project, but i don't know where. I uploaded it to show .js file that is responsible for creating enemies and i want to check collision in "player" .js file. Is there a way to get value of variable from other file (information about enemy posistion X from enemies.js  TO gracz.js), or i have to write code in one file to get that information?

Comment: This has nothing to do with including other JS files. The JavaScript interpreter will work on the whole code, so you just have to define your variable at toplevel and initialize it before trying to use it.

Comment: Can u give me an example? I want to get variable where its value is changed in function from one js file to another, and constantly read its value. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Simply create a var at toplevel, really. Nothing magic in this.

Comment: i did what u told me. Firstly created var pozX in enemies js.file but when I try to read its value in gracz. js file i get "cannot read property 'pozX' of undefined"                                                                                         var mob = start.mobki,                               "document.write(Math.round(mob.pozX));" this is how i try to read it

Comment: Let's call your global data "context". First you will have to declare "var context" anywhere at toplevel. The declaration will be hoisted before execution start, so the place you do it does not matter much. Then initialize it before trying to use it (typically in the document.onload event). Then you can use it.

Comment: I think i did what u write above but it didnt work. Can u plz show me from my jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/q4wyz7na/1/ how to do it? I tried and tried but I really dont get it how to get this variable. I'm young programmer so  sorry for stupid questions.